# xPath and Google

Tags: php, parsing, dom, xpath

I would like to parse web page (only Google links) using xpath...
So I done a test, and it will return "Found 0 links"
With many tries, I don't found any solution...

For example :
I wrote some words in a input box, and this file will show the 10 links present on the fisrt google search page.

My source code :

```
    <?php 
    <!-- Code for DOMDocument and page recuperation are not detailled here -->
    <!-- xPath : only links are parse -->
    $nodes = $xpath->query(".//*[@id='rso']/li[position() > 1][position() < 11]/div/h3/a");
    ?>
    <html>
    <body>
    <?php

<!-- Show the links -->    
    if($nodes)
    {  
        echo '<h1>les <span class="red">'.$nodes->length. '</span> liens de la page : '.$url.'</h1>';

        echo '<table>
                <thead><th>url</th></thead><tbody>';
        foreach($nodes as $node) {
            if($node->getAttribute('href')){$href = $node->getAttribute('href');}else{$rel= "-";}

            echo '<tr><td>'. $href .'</td></tr>';   
        }

        echo '</tbody></table>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'aucun lien trouvé';
    }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

After lot of research, I do :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Scraping avec DOMDocument & DOMXpath</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
// Alexa Sites Linking to Insolite-du-Geek
$url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=jobs';
$queryXPath = '/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div[6]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/ol/li/div/h3/a';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
$x = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodeList = $x->query($queryXPath );
foreach ($nodeList as $node) 
    echo utf8_decode(urldecode($node->nodeValue))."<br/>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

But, I'm focused on the last one, and the result is nothing ...

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Goole? Google links? Do you mean that you want to spider and parse the result pages of the Google search engine? Otherwise, please edit the question and clarify what your source HTML looks like.

Comment: Sorry for this errors...
I would like to show Google search links...

Comment: The problem will most probably have to do with how you load the Google search result, don't hide it. Anyway: Google offers a search API, don't program against their website!

Comment: Thanks, but after, i would like to save URLs in variables...

Answer (score 0):

my friend try it:

```
$xpath->query('//h3[@class="r"]//a');
```

for me work fine.